# Implementing Output Caching using VaryByCustom: where does the custom string go?

Tags: c#, asp.net, caching

I'm following this [MSDN tutorial](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5ecf4420.asp) to implement a custom caching mechanism. In the Global.asax, I added this:

```
public override string GetVaryByCustomString(HttpContext context, string arg)
{
    if (arg == "minorversion")
    {
        return "Version=" + context.Request.Browser.MinorVersion.ToString();
    }
    return base.GetVaryByCustomString(context, arg);
}
```

And in the aspx files, I added this: `<%@ OutputCache Duration="10" VaryByParam="None" VaryByCustom="minorversion" %>` at the top of the page.

What I don't understand is how to use `Response.Cache.SetVaryByCustom("minorversion");` and where to set the string parameter that sets the caching based on a string at runtime. For instance, if in the `Page_Load` function of the code-behind file I set a string variable called `TheLanguage` then how and where do I specify that I want the cache to vary by the value of this string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the work is done in the global.asax method, GetVaryByCustomString. You can specify the name of the customstring by which you want your page to vary, and you can name this anything you want, but that is just used as a key into the GetVaryByCustomString method.

As is shown in the tutorial, if you want to vary based on e.g. "minor version" you can create a name for this ("minorversion") and then implement it based on the context.Request.Browser.MinorVersion.ToString(). For each variation of the string that is returned by GetVaryByCustomString and the arg that was provided, you will get a different cached output.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the answer. I actually realized that I could do the caching by varying the URL and that therefore I didn't even need the varybycustom. Thanks anyway, upvoted and accepted in case it helps others.